# How do I find the final boss in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I'm playing the last unstable version (not nightly).

I've managed to obtain all artefacts and opened the gate in the Ark Ruins and teleported to the Ruin (planet) where the final boss should be.

But how do I find him? I've tried to dig to the bottom of the planet and found nothing but a bottomless pit. I've walked the full circle on the surface and again found nothing.

I guess he is buried somewhere underground, but the planet is huge! Are there any tricks to find him quickly?

Comment: I thought the game doesn't come out until Friday. When you are playing the nightly builds: AFAIK the boss fights are removed from that version.

Comment: @Philipp I'm playing Unstable. It was updated with those new features a week or two ago.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I recall reading somewhere that Chucklefish (the dev team) removed some of the bosses from the unstable/nightly builds in order to prevent spoilers for the official release. It might have been on their daily update blog on their website.

Comment: @MageXy That would explain it, but I've seen all the other bosses. (Arena bosses disappeared for me, but it seems to be a bug. It would make no sense to remove them while leaving every other boss.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final boss is in the unstable branch right now, and presumably has been since they pushed 1.0 to unstable last week.

The bottomless pit you speak of isn't actually bottomless. I was confused myself, since the advice SAIL gives gave me the impression I wasn't supposed to go down any farther.

Get down the pit (descending platforms or dumping a few thousand blocks of collapsing material like sand or slime can help), and then walk left or right continuously. You'll find the boss fairly quickly since it's a smaller planet.

Comment: Well, that's pretty stupid SAIL I must say. Digging down was the first thing I tried and then he told me to stop. What a buggy AI. =/ (I guess that advice is supposed to be said on real planets with bottomless pits. Bug?) Anyway, thanks for helping me to save the universe!

Answer (score -2):

I typed /admin and fell down the pit. I hit the bottom and took like 500 damage but as an admin you can't die. Then the boss room was down there. Typed /admin again to stop being invincible.